# MATLAB - fzero initial guess

Tags: matlab, function

I've been searching stackoverflow for some help with this issue, but haven't found anything thus far so, hence, I'm now seeking some advice.

Basically, I'm using the fzero function to solve for an unknown variable in an equation, where the values of all the other variables in the equation are known. An initial guess for fzero works fine for a single set of values for the "other variables" in the equation. However, I have a range of values for the "other variables" - which are known - and I would like to solve for the unknown variable across this range of values. As the range spans from 20 to 250, a single initial guess will not satisfy the fzero function, and I get an error. Is there any way of estimating an accurate(ish) initial guess value for each point within my 20-250 range?

Hope I explained my problem well...I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you now the guesses you want to use for the values of your range, this can be done in a for-loop. Certainly not very fast, but i think the example would work.

```
 guesses = [1 2 3 4 ...your guesses....guess(i)];
 range = [9 8 7 6 ....your values....value(i)]

 for i = 1:length(guesses)
 f = @x range(i)*sin(x);
 x(i) = fzero(f,guess(i))

 end
```